# Perl: array of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have this in JSON format. How do i extract the titles and values and add them to my existing hash (`%movies`)?

```
{ 'WarMovies' => [ { 'Lone Survivor' => 1 }, { 'Black Hawk Down' => 1 } ] }
```

Comment: There are many modules that can read JSON in Perl, see for example [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS)

Comment: Can you show your hash, and whatever other code you have?

Comment: what are the keys and values of your existing hash?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you need help with decoding the JSON, merging the data structures, or something else? It will be much easier for us to identify the problem if you provide a small runnable program that we can run and see the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $input = { 'WarMovies' => [ { 'Lone Survivor' => 1 }, { 'Black Hawk Down' => 1 } ] };
my %movies = ();

foreach my $genre (keys(%$input)) {
    #print Dumper($genre);
    foreach my $movie_hash (@{$input->{$genre}}) {
        my @titles = keys(%$movie_hash);
        foreach my $title (@titles) {
            $movies{$title} = 1;
        }
    }
}

print Dumper(\%movies);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my $input = { 'WarMovies' => [ { 'Lone Survivor' => 1 }, { 'Black Hawk Down' => 1 } ] };
my %movies = ();
map { my ($key) = keys(%$_); $movies{$key} = 1 } @{$input->{WarMovies}};
print Dumper(\%movies);
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer.

Comment: @jtym For this code to work the line `use Data::Dumper;` should be included. Besides do you know if it would be possible to store and extract hash elements by using PDL? As something a bit similar I know that numpy has [record arrays](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/numpy/python-numpy-exercise-190.php).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise way to extract the titles from your hashref by chaining `map` to deference the nested refs.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hashref = { 'WarMovies' => [ { 'Lone Survivor' => 1 }, { 'Black Hawk Down' => 1 } ] };
my @titles = map { keys %$_ } map { @{$hashref->{$_}} } keys %$hashref;
```